# Vue 3 script setup components not recognized by IDE

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, webstorm, vue-script-setup

I have created npm library that is installed on another project through package.json. The library is created in Vue3. The problem is that components that are created with script setup are not recognized by IDE (WebStorm) and components that are created with Options API (without script setup) are recognized. Both components works, but the problem is that for example `test-input` component is not recognized and `test-button` components is.

vite.config.ts

```
build: {
  cssCodeSplit: false,
  lib: {
    entry: './src/TestDesignSystemPlugin.ts',
    formats: ['es', 'cjs'],
    name: 'TestDesignSystemPlugin',
    fileName: (format) => (format === 'es' ? 'index.js' : 'index.cjs'),
  },
  rollupOptions: {
    external: ['vue'],
    output: {
      globals: {
        vue: 'Vue',
      },
    },
  },
},
```

TestButton.vue - Component created with Options API

```
<template>
  <button>
    <slot />
  </button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'TestButton',
})
</script>
```

TestInput.vue - Component created with Composition API

```
<template>
  <input v-model="model" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const model = ref('')
</script>
```

Also this is `TestDesignSystemPlugin.ts` file that is used in vite.config.ts and where components are installed:

```
import type { App } from 'vue'
import {
  TestButton,
  TestInput,
} from '@/components'

export default {
  install: (app: App) => {
    app.component('TestButton', TestButton)
    app.component('TestInput', TestInput)
  },
}
```

UPDATE:

I don't think that issue is with IDE, than with the build of the library (plugin). When I see index.js of the build I see the difference between components that are with setup and without setup:

```
var TestDesignSystemPlugin = {
  install: (app) => {
    app.component("TestButton", TestButton);
    app.component("TestButtonSocial", TestButtonSocial);
    app.component("TestInput", _sfc_main$8);
  }
};
```

Comment: Which version of WebStorm IDE are you using? I can see the support for the Composition API has been added some time ago: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2020/03/webstorm-2020-1-eap-8/.

Also, you are using <script setup> which has been added quite recently: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49000#focus=Comments-27-4909862.0-0.

Comment: The terminology is wrong. It's not options vs composition, it's script vs script setup which is a totally different case. That you have this problem suggests that script setup isn't supported with current ide version. The question is specific to ide, not vue in general.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the post and changed the terminology. Also I have updated the question. I don't think that the issue is in the IDE, than in the build itself. As I see components with script tag are assigned to variable like _sfc_main$8 and probably because of that are not recognized.